# Pending transaction since 5 days and connection 3 years since last blok

Tags: pending-transactions

I made an ethereum transfer between two accounts but the transaction is pending since the last 5 days and I read connection "3 years since last bloc" on the top of the wallet.
Please can you help me?
Tanks in advance.

Comment: Which wallet are you using? Did you search the transaction hash in a block explorer? If the wallet is disconnected from the network then it is unlikely the transaction will be mined.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your interest, I'm using Ethereum Wallet version 0.11.1. I checked the transaction on Etherscan but i didn't find it. If I  click on transaction code I only read this message on Etherscan: "Sorry, We are unable to locate this TxnHash".

Comment: Ethereum Wallet was deprecated a couple of years ago. You should have a .json or UTC file with the private key. That file can be imported into other wallets like MyEtherWallet, MyCrypto or Metamask.

Comment: Thank you so much, I try and I let you know.

Comment: Every think ok, thank you so much for you support.